# How can I free this 2D calloc'd array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, free, calloc

I'm doing an assignment for my C algorithms class and I have a memory allocation as follows:

```
Graph* new_graph = (Graph*)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
new_graph->adjacency_matrix = malloc(num_nodes*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < num_nodes; j++) {
            new_graph->adjacency_matrix[i] = calloc(sizeof(int), num_nodes);
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying to free the memory I'm doing it as follows, but valgrind keeps saying I have lost 1,176 bytes in 42 blocks due to my calloc.

```
void delete_graph(Graph *g) {
    for(int i = 0; i < g->num_vertices; i++) {
        free(g->adjacency_matrix[i]);
    }
    free(g->adjacency_matrix);
    free(g);
}
```

The size of num_nodes is 7, so I'm assuming only the first row is being freed or something, but I've tried freeing it with another for loop etc., but i keep getting the same errors. Would really appreciate any help with this thanks!

Comment: The problem is you're allocating memory for a new row... but for _every cell_. Also, shouldn't you be setting ` new_graph->adjacency_matrix`, not ` new_graph->adjacency_matrix[i]` ?

Comment: Rule #1 in memory management: Every call to `malloc` must be matched be exactly one call to `free`. You can switch it around and say that every call to `free` must be matched by a `malloc`. Looking at your `delete_graph`, you see that there is one loop calling `free`. So why do you have two nested loops calling `malloc`? Remove the `j` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I free this 2D calloc'd array in C?

You can't.... because your allocation is wrong.

In the allocation this line

```
for(int j = 0; j < num_nodes; j++) {
```

seems wrong. You keep overwriting the same pointer as you only use `i` as index and therefore generates memory leaks.

Let's say that `num_nodes` is 2

Then your code is doing:

```
new_graph->adjacency_matrix[0] = calloc(sizeof(int), num_nodes);
new_graph->adjacency_matrix[0] = calloc(sizeof(int), num_nodes); // LEAK
new_graph->adjacency_matrix[1] = calloc(sizeof(int), num_nodes);
new_graph->adjacency_matrix[1] = calloc(sizeof(int), num_nodes); // LEAK
```

So you are allocating memory and saving the pointer... fine, but the you overwrite the same pointer with a new allocation. That's a memory leak that can't be recovered.

Comment: The code is creating a 2D array to make a graph, so I needed the nested loops because I had to allocate memory to each node of the graph. num_nodes is the same value as g->num_vertices. When I try and free with nested loops, it gives a segfault and the same with when I try free i = 0; i < (g->num_vertices)* (g->num_vertices) amount of times

Comment: @olearyd3 Ask your self: What do you use `j` for.... that tells it all. Plenty of memory leaks

Comment: i don't understand sorry. The question i am trying to solve with the code was to do with using an adjacency matrix and pathfinding with Dijkstra's algorithm, so I had to make a 2D array using i and j for the adjacency matrix to create a graph. I don't know how to free it since everything I have tried either gives segfaults, still has memory left in the heap or just doesn't work

Comment: @olearyd3 Consider `i` equal to 0... then you keep assigning `new_graph->adjacency_matrix[0] = calloc(sizeof(int), num_nodes);` again and again.

Comment: @olearyd3 Answer edited to make your bug more clear

Comment: yes, so say num_nodes = 7, it allocates memory for slots [0][0] up to [7][7]. I just need help with freeing the memory, the allocation works fine, as far as I'm aware, since my code works as it's supposed to except for not freeing enough memory. I've tried freeing more memory as I said, but it just gives seg faults.

Comment: @olearyd3 You are not reading my answer!!!! You can't free the memory!!! The bug is in your allocation... not in `free`

Comment: I just saw it, but I still don;t understand what you're saying I should do to fix the problem. I tried using malloc instead and I tried callocing for [i][j] before, but they just gave errors. This was the only allocation that worked, so I've no idea what to change as any time I try, the code no longer seems to work

Comment: @olearyd3 Your question is about `free` but that is **not** your problem. Your problem is the allocation.

Comment: how would I fix the allocation then?

Comment: @olearyd3 Can't tell from the code you have posted. Too much information missing. I can't tell what you are trying to do but your current code is just wrong.

Comment: that's ok, thanks anyway!